# Mongodb How to pivot fields?

Tags: mongodb

I have collection in mongo db, 
so I want the fields: Ip    UtilizationReports.Start    UtilizationReports.CpuReports.0.ProcName    UtilizationReports.CpuReports.0.MaxUsage    UtilizationReports.CpuReports.1.ProcName    UtilizationReports.CpuReports.1.MaxUsage

for that I use this this code:

```
db.Agents.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "UtilizationReports.Start" : 0.0, 
                "UtilizationReports.Interval" : 0.0, 
                "UtilizationReports.LastLogin" : 0.0, 
                "Configuration" : 0.0, 
                "HealthReports" : 0.0, 
                "_id" : 0.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : {
                "path" : "$UtilizationReports.CpuReports"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "UtilizationReports.CpuReports.0" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                }, 
                "UtilizationReports.0.CpuReports.0.ProcName" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

and I get this data

[image]

but I want to pivot row "ProcName" to column and the value will be "MaxUsage"

I try this code but it doesn't work:

```
db.Agents.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "tmp" : {
                    "$arrayToObject" : {
                        "$zip" : {
                            "inputs" : [
                                "$items.key", 
                                "$items.value"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "Ip" : "$Ip", 
                    "StartReport" : "$UtilizationReports.Start"
                }, 
                "items" : {
                    "$addToSet" : {
                        "key" : "$UtilizationReports.CpuReports.ProcName", 
                        "value" : "$UtilizationReports.CpuReports.MaxUsage"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$addFields" : {
                "tmp.Ip" : "$_id.Ip", 
                "tmp.StartReport" : "$_id.StartReport"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$replaceRoot" : {
                "newRoot" : "$tmp"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

the error message:
ad projection specification, cannot include fields or add computed fields during an exclusion projection: { UtilizationReports.Interval: 0.0, UtilizationReports.LastLogin: 0.0, Configuration: 0.0, HealthReports: 0.0, _id: 0.0, tmp: { $arrayToObject: { $zip: { inputs: [ \"$items.key\", \"$items.value\" ]

The sample output:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide sample inputs and the associated output?

Comment: I will provide it in some min

Answer (score 0):

$arrayToObject is New in version 3.6.
I use with mongoDB version 3.4

Comment: but, do you have other way to do that?